# How to compare two tables row by row in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two temporary tables with single column

***Table 1***

```
MaXAge   (Contains maximum age of each kind)
-----------
15
15
11
```

***Table 2***

```
KGroup  (Contains  each kind)
--------------------------------------------------
Cat
Dog
Parrot
```

AND another Table Pets with fields

```
PetID   Name   Kind   Gender  Age   OwnerID
```

NOW, I want to display name of animals with maximum age group by kind

Comment: If you don't have a direct relationship between the two tables you won't be able to do what you want.

Comment: Tables have no inherent ordering, so there is no logic available to say the "First" record in Table1 matches with the "First" record in Table2. The concept just doesn't exist to say "First" (or any ordinal) like it would in Excel or a CSV. You can order a result set though. `SELECT KGroup FROM Table2 ORDER BY KGroup ASC` but of course that means nothing in this context since it seems like you are wanting to rely on an inherent ordering that doesn't exist.

Comment: If you had an ID field for each table to create the relationship between the two temp tables that would allow you to do what you want. Such as ID of 1 = Cat, 2 = Dog and so on. You could then join based on ID of Animal Kind and get your data.

Comment: In your temporary tables also include an "ID" column to link them. For example, 15 in first table might be related to Cat, Dog or Parrot, who knows? Instead the first should have 1,2,3 as Ids as well as the second. And it is also questionable why do you have 2 such temporary tables instead of one simple (Id, Group, MaxAge).

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using any temp tables

```
SELECT name, age
FROM pets p
JOIN (SELECT kind, MAX(age) max_age FROM pets GROUP BY kind) AS sub ON sub.kind = p.kind AND sub.max_age = p.age
```